# counsel-M-x search for command names optionally beginning with my:

Tags: regular-expressions, counsel

## Goal

Use `counsel-M-x` to browse commands that begin with a particular character, except that they may be optionally prefixed by `my:`

## Example

`counsel-M-x` >> `^org` matches commands beginning with `org`

I need `counsel-M-x` >> `<x>org` (for some `<x>`) to match commands beginning with `org` or `my:org`

The regex `^\(my:\)?org` matches the desired strings, but `counsel-M-x` >> `^\(my:\)?org` doesn't work, because I don't think `counsel-M-x` works on regex's in general.